# Using SQL to convert directed edges into undirected edges

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

The raw data table is

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| node_1 | node_2 | weight |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 |      2 |      5 |
|      1 |      3 |     10 |
|      2 |      1 |     21 |
|      1 |      4 |     15 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is a directed weighted graph. What I want is to convert the directed graph to undirected graph like

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| node_1 | node_2 | weight |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 |      2 |     26 |
|      1 |      3 |     10 |
|      1 |      4 |     15 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Having an edge(1,3) does not mean there exists an edge(3,1).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How does 1<->2 have weight 26? It is possible to convert undirected to directed, but not the other way around.

Comment: @PaulDraper Because the weight from node_1 to node_2 is 5 and the weight from node_2 to node_1 is 21, their sum is 26.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to sum the weights for the undirected nodes.
Your example leaves unclear if there can be multiple directed edges between the same nodes (i.e.  1->2, 1->2, 1->2), but here I assume they should be merged too

I don't have a PSQL database handy to test this on, but this is pretty vanilla SQL, so you should be OK.

DISCLAIMER: please try it with the ROLLBACK first, on a test-table. Don't trust your real data to stranger's advice on the internet, especially if they have 1-rep :-)

The trick here is that it is very hard to group over two columns that are interchangeable (node_1, node_2), so that's why I first rearrange them to be non-interchangeable/ordered

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  -- 1a) Make a temporary place to hold our values
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tempnodes (int low_node, int high_node, int weight)
    ON COMMIT DROP;

  -- 1b) consistently write the nodes to temp
  -- making sure node_1 always <= node_2
  -- this ordering helps our grouping in the next step
  INSERT INTO temptable (low_node, high_node, weight)
    SELECT least(node_1, node_2), greatest(node_1, node_2), weight
    FROM oldtable;

  -- 2a) Create a place for our new data
  -- Alternatively, you could truncate the old table
  -- and write the new values back there
  -- however, this way we can go back if/when we make a mistake
  CREATE TABLE newtable(int low_node, int high_node, int summed_weight);

  -- 2b) merge the edges 
  INSERT INTO newtable( low_node, high_node, summed_weight)
    SELECT low_node, high_node, sum(weight)
    FROM temptable
    GROUP BY low_node, high_node;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: compared to @pratik's answer, mine is less elegant, requiring a temporary table.
I do humbly suggest that my answer is less destructive by selecting into a new table, just in case you later decide that weight-summing wasn't what was needed after all (e.g. weight averaging, etc.)

Comment: `min(node_1, node_2)` and `max(node_1, node_2)` are invalid. You probably want `least` and `greatest`.

Comment: Thanks. I need to write the results into a new table exactly.

Comment: re: @a_horse_with_no_name 's solution, his "group by least(), greatest()" construct trumps my temporary table in terms of elegance, and probably memory-usage as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or need to) actually change the data, you can do this with a single select:

```
select least(node_1, node_2) as node_1, 
       greatest(node_2, node_1) as node_2, 
       sum(weight) as weight
from graph
group by least(node_1, node_2), greatest(node_2, node_1)
order by 1,2;
```

If you need both, the directed and undirected graph, you can turn the above into a view.

Similar to pratik's answer this can be combined into a single statement that changes the underlying table:

```
with directed_graph as (
  select least(node_1, node_2) as node_1, 
         greatest(node_2, node_1) as node_2, 
         sum(weight) as weight
  from graph
  group by least(node_1, node_2), greatest(node_2, node_1)
), 
new_graph as (
  update graph 
    set weight = dg.weight
  from directed_graph dg
  where (graph.node_1, graph.node_2) = (dg.node_1, dg.node_2)
  returning graph.*
)
delete from graph 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from new_graph ng
                  where ng.node_1 = graph.node_1 
                    and ng.node_2 = graph.node_2);
```

Here is a SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad5b7/1

Comment: Thank you! It works. Here is another question. I would use your first solution to create a new table. But the raw table contains more than 100 million rows. So the computing efficiency is crucial. Both your answer and pratik garg 's can solve this question. Which one is more efficient? Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben: I would assume that the update part is pretty much the same in terms of performance. Pratik's solution could use indexes defined on node_1 and node_2, whereas for my solution you will need to create an index on the expression `least(node_1, node_2), greatest(node_2, node_1)`

Comment: I applied your method. I added two columns: node_least and node_greatest. And 'UPDATE graph SET node_least=least(node_1,node_2), node_greatest=greatest(node_1,node_2)'. Then I would add index on node_least and node_greatest. But after 36 hours passed, the update is still running. Why is the update so slow? Is there any other efficient method to add these two columns?

Comment: @Ben: Sounds like your update is blocked by some other session. If that is not the case, the please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and post a new question

Answer (score 1):

you need to use update and delete both statement to get this solved.

```
UPDATE test_prit_1 t_1
   SET weight = weight + coalesce((SELECT t_2.weight
                               FROM test_prit_1 t_2
                              WHERE t_2.node_1 = t_1.node_2
                                AND t_2.node_2 = t_1.node_1
                                AND t_2.node_1 > t_2.node_2),
                             0)
```

and then delete statement to delete the extra rows (in given sample node_1 = 2 and node_2 = 1)

```
DELETE FROM test_prit_1 t_1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM test_prit_1 t_2
         WHERE t_2.node_1 = t_1.node_2
           AND t_2.node_2 = t_1.node_1
           AND t_2.node_2 > t_2.node_1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I learned the coalesce function. Can you help me with the computing efficiency question I asked a_horse_with_no_name?